# Trainable Matrix multiplication Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I'm trying to build a (custom) trainable matrix-multiplication layer in TensorFlow, but things aren't working out...  More precisely, my model should look like this:

```
x -> A(x) x
```

where A(x) is a feed-forward network with values in the n x n matrix (and thus depends on the input x) and A(x) is matrix by vector multiplication.

**Here's what I've coded-up:**

```
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, units=16, input_dim=32):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.Tw1 = self.add_weight(name='Weights_1 ',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                                    initializer='GlorotUniform',
                                    trainable=True)
        
        self.Tw2 = self.add_weight(name='Weights_2 ',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1], (self.units)**2),
                                    initializer='GlorotUniform',
                                    trainable=True)
        
        self.Tb = self.add_weight(name='basies',
                                    shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                    initializer='GlorotUniform',#Previously 'ones'
                                    trainable=True)

        
    def call(self, input):
        # Build Vector-Valued Feed-Forward Network
        ffNN = tf.matmul(input, self.Tw1) + self.Tb
        ffNN = tf.nn.relu(ffNN)
        ffNN = tf.matmul(ffNN, self.Tw2) 
    
        
        # Map to Matrix
        ffNN = tf.reshape(ffNN, [self.units,self.units])

        # Multiply Matrix-Valued function with input data
        x_out = tf.matmul(ffNN,input)
        
        # Return Output
        return x_out
```

**Now I build the model:**

```
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=[2])
output_layer  = custom_layer(2)(input_layer)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output_layer])

# Compile Model
#----------------#
# Define Optimizer
optimizer_on = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=10**(-1))
# Compile
model.compile(loss = 'mse',
                optimizer = optimizer_on,
                metrics = ['mse'])

# Fit Model
#----------------#
model.fit(data_x, data_y, epochs=(10**1), verbose=0)
```

**and then I get this error message:**

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 128 values, but the requested shape has 4
     [[node model_62/reconfiguration_unit_70/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-176-0b494fa3fc75>:46) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_175181]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_62/reconfiguration_unit_70/Reshape:
 model_62/reconfiguration_unit_70/MatMul_1 (defined at <ipython-input-176-0b494fa3fc75>:41)

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

**Thoughts:**
It seems like something is wrong with the network dimensions but I can't figure what/how to repair it...

Comment: in tf.reshape... tangential_ffNN is not defined anywhere

Comment: @MarcoCerliani  Sorry forgot to rename that it should read 'ffNN'.

Comment: ok, in x_out... you are trying to do a dot product between ffNN = (batch_dim, 2,2) and input = (batch_dim, 2) which will raise error... which is your desired shape? (the shape of data_y)

Comment: the desired shape is a d x d matrix which is then multiplied with the input tensor

Comment: ok but the error persists... you can't do a dot product between (batch_dim, d,d) and (batch_dim, d)

Comment: oh, then how could one implement x -> A(x) -> A(x) x then?  (where A(x) is a feed-forward network taking values in n x n matrices?)

Comment: you can expand your input in x_out in order to go from (batch_dim, d) to (batch_dim, d,d)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you post it in an answer?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani  Yes, I've beeing tinkering with data_y.shape but its not working..

Comment: tell me the shape of data_y

Comment: data_y is of shape [N,1] where N is the size of the sample.

Comment: this simply sounds not possible, I can see how a dot between (N, d) and (N, d, d) can do (N,1)... I think u must rethink about the whole problem... I don't see a way out